# Replacing multiple occurences of a character in a string with python

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to replace words like goooooooooooood with good. For this i tried

```
t.replace(r'(.)\2+',r'\2')
```

where t is some word like gooooooooooood

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Does not make sense, why should goooooooooooood be good and not god?

Comment: `t` seems to be a string, that means you're not using regex but regular character replacement here.

Comment: when a user types in gooooood, he's most likely referring to good and not god eg: the burger here was goooooooooooood

Comment: And what is the expected result for baaaaad?

Comment: @user1747696: How is the program supposed to know which to use, one or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex solution

```
import re

s = "goooooooooooooood"
print re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1', s)
```

or

```
print re.sub(r'(.)\1{3,}', r'\1\1', s)
```

To replace gooooooooooood with good

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a spell checker. There are multiple ways of doing it but few ways I found useful is

- [Fuzzy Wuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)
- [Difflib.SequenceMatcher.find_longest_match](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)
- [Spell Checker using Probability](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)
- [PyEnchant](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [53]: strs="goooooooooooood"

In [54]: from itertools import groupby

In [55]: "".join(k*2 if len(list(g))>=2 else k for k,g in groupby(strs))
Out[55]: 'good'
```